# Prove that $~f(z)=(z+1)^n~$ will be differentiable.

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers, proof-writing

I was messing around with the Cauchy-Riemann equations and noticed, that for all different $$f(z)=(z+1)^n~,$$ where $~n~$ can be any positive integer.

I've tried the Cauchy-Riemann equations were satisfied. Therefore, it got me wondering how could something like this be proven that for any n the equations will be satisfied?

Comment: You can prove it straight from the definition, using binomial expansion.

Comment: If you know that they solve Cauchy-Riemann iff they are expressible as a Taylor series around every point, then note that you have expressed the function as a taylor series around $z=-1$. The only non-zero coefficient is the $n$th one, and that coefficient is 1.